# ffmpeg - Audio Issues with TS File

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to the world of ffmpeg, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question or request.

I'm in the process of trying to convert a .ts file to a h264/mp4. I was able to successfully convert the video, however whenever I go to play the output file, the audio is weird. Most of the audio is only coming through the left channel. I noticed that the audio has multiple channels - 6 to be exact. And there are two audio streams as well. I'm assuming that this has something to do with it, but I am not sure what exactly to put in the command line to fix it.

I was hoping there would be a way to copy the video stream from the mp4 I had already made with ffmpeg, and then replace the audio from that mp4 with the audio from the source ts file - preferably mixed down into regular stereo audio. It is quite a big file, so I would like to not have to convert the video stream again if I don't have to.

Here is the media information from the source video.

```
General
ID : 1 (0x1)
Complete name : D:\88th Annual Christmas in Rockefeller Center.ts
Format : MPEG-TS
File size : 9.80 GiB
Duration : 2 h 7 min
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 11.0 Mb/s
Law rating : None

Video
ID : 101 (0x65)
Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
Format : MPEG Video
Format version : Version 2
Format profile : Main@High
Format settings : BVOP
Format settings, BVOP : Yes
Format settings, Matrix : Default
Format settings, GOP : Variable
Format settings, picture structure : Frame
Codec ID : 2
Duration : 2 h 7 min
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 9 851 kb/s
Maximum bit rate : 80.0 Mb/s
Width : 1 920 pixels
Height : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Active Format Description : Full frame 16:9 image
Frame rate : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Interlaced
Scan order : Top Field First
Compression mode : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.159
Time code of first frame : 00:00:00;00
Time code source : Group of pictures header
Stream size : 8.80 GiB (90%)

Audio #1
ID : 102 (0x66)
Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
Format : AC-3
Format/Info : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name : Dolby Digital
Codec ID : 129
Duration : 2 h 7 min
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 384 kb/s
Channel(s) : 6 channels
Channel layout : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Compression mode : Lossy
Delay relative to video : 32 ms
Stream size : 351 MiB (3%)
Language : English
Service kind : Complete Main

Audio #2
ID : 7543 (0x1D77)
Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
Format : AC-3
Format/Info : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name : Dolby Digital
Codec ID : 129
Duration : 2 h 7 min
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 192 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Channel layout : L R
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Compression mode : Lossy
Delay relative to video : 11 ms
Stream size : 176 MiB (2%)
Language : Spanish
Service kind : Complete Main

Text #1
ID : 101 (0x65)-CC1
Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
Format : EIA-608
Muxing mode : A/53 / DTVCC Transport
Muxing mode, more info : Muxed in Video #1
Duration : 2 h 7 min
Bit rate mode : Constant
Stream size : 0.00 Byte (0%)
CaptionServiceName : CC1

Text #2
ID : 101 (0x65)-1
Menu ID : 1 (0x1)
Format : EIA-708
Muxing mode : A/53 / DTVCC Transport
Muxing mode, more info : Muxed in Video #1
Duration : 2 h 7 min
Bit rate mode : Constant
Stream size : 0.00 Byte (0%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During FFmpeg converting you can choose what exactly should happen with the audio and video streams.

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 output.mp4
```

The example above converts only the video to h264 and copys the audio streams. The `-map` commands tells FFmpeg how many output streams you have. The first map is your video. The `-map 0:a:0` tells FFmpeg to use from the first input file (first 0) the first audio stream (a:0). To add also the second audio stream just add an additional map command `-map 0:a:1` (a:1 for the second audio).

If you now want to re-mux the content:

```
ffmpeg -i original.ts -i converted.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 1:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 output.mp4
```

The commands above is untested but should work.